# Python/smtplib - automation for sending email

Tags: python, smtp

I am developing an application to automate the sending of emails from the collection department where I work. It consists of accessing an excel spreadsheet, reading the column that is missing the payment and sending an automatic email to the customer. The code works, but it sends the email only to the last person who did not make the payment and not to everyone. can you help me? Follow the code below:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
from datetime import date
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/temp/cobranca.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

lastCol = sheet.max_column
latestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value

unpaidMembers = {}
for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=lastCol).value
    if payment != 'ok':
        name = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
        email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
        unpaidMembers[name] = email
        print(unpaidMembers)

# create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()

# setup the parameters of the message
password = "example"
msg['From'] = "example@example.com"
msg['To'] = email
msg['Subject'] = "%s - Honorário em aberto." % (name)

for name, email in unpaidMembers.items():
    body = "Prezado(a) %s. \n \n Em nosso sistema consta, em sua conta, o honorário referente ao mês %s/2020 em aberto, pedimos sua regularização imediata. \n \n Caso o pagamento já tenha sido efetuado, por favor, desconsidere este e-mail. \n \n \n Att, \n OMNIA Tecnologia" % (
    name, latestMonth)
    print('Sending email to %s...' % email)

# add in the message body
msg.attach(MIMEText(body))

# create server
server = smtplib.SMTP('stmp.example.net', 587)

server.starttls()

# Login Credentials for sending the mail
server.login(msg['From'], password)

# send the message via the server.
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

server.quit()

print("successfully sent email to %s:" % (msg['To']))
```

Answer (score 0):

`msg['To']` can be given a list of email addresses.  Possibly making a list as shown below is an option.

```py
email=[]
unpaidMembers = {}
for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=lastCol).value
    if payment != 'ok':
        name = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
        email.append(sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value)
        unpaidMembers[name] = email
        print(unpaidMembers)
```

then

```
msg['To'] = email
```

Comment: You *really* don't want the recipients to see the addresses of each other in the `To:` header! `Bcc:` almost solves this, but could still expose recipients in the same domain to each other. You really want to send an individual message to each recipient (and customize each enough to make it not look like spam; including the recipient's real name in the body is a good start, but perhaps not sufficient). Taking care not to send several messages to the same mail server in rapid succession is probably also a good idea).

Comment: @Stuber he returned the following error:  `email.append(row=r, column=2).value
TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments`